# How to change a target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, target

I've downloaded a project from github and it contains 2 targets, one library and one test executable.

I suspect its current target is set to the library because Xcode's build&run is disabled.(I can only build)

How can I change the target to the test executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the popup next to the "Stop" button to select the active target.

Comment: Apparently the developer hasn't created a [scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html) for the second target. You can do that by selecting "Manage Schemes..." from the menu. Then click the `+` button and select the other target.

Comment: wow thanks for fast response, I can't still run after adding the other target.. what would be the cause? Second target(jastortests) is not executable either? :( https://github.com/elado/jastor

Comment: The second target is a unit test target, you can run the tests by selecting "Test" from the "Product" menu or pressing `⌘U`

Comment: Actually, the existing scheme is configured to use the unit test target for testing anyway, so you don't really need to create a second scheme for that.